# Mongoose filter elements based on other collection

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema, mongoose-populate

I have three collections :

1. `User` which has some user data

   `id: ObjectId`
2. `Post` which is a post an `User` can make - it has a ref to `User.id`

   `id: ObjectId
   author: {ref: 'User'}
   text: String
   datePosted: Date`
3. `User.reports` which is an association between `User.id` and `Post.id`, a document in this collection means that an `User` has reported a `Post`.

   `id: ObjectId
   user: {ref: 'User'}
   post: {ref: 'Post'}
   dateReported: Date`

The `Posts` can be huge (thousands), so when I retrieve them I do some infinite scroll - get the 10 latest, then the next 10 etc....

This is my query :

```
        let posts = await Post.find()
        .skip(start) //0 initial
        .limit(step) //step is 10
        .populate('author')
        .sort('-datePosted')
        .exec();

    return res.json(posts);
```

My question is : How do I skip the `Posts` reported by the `User` - which are in the `User.reports` collection, and always return the right amount of `Posts` (in this case 10) ?

Comment: Seeing you Post and User schemas would help a lot

Comment: I've updated the Schemas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see what you’re getting at now. So, basically you want to use the $nin operator in your find query to eliminate ids that are in an array of Post ids that the user has reported.

In your current schema, that means running two queries, first to retrieve reported post ids from your reports collection matching the user, and then running the query like:

```
   Post.find( { _id: { $nin: arrayOfPostIds }}).....
```

If you are able to just put the reports in the user schema it’s easier, as it saves a query, but I recognize there are cases where it’s better to have them in their own collection too.

Comment: Ok, so there's no way to accomplish this with only one query (keeping the given schema) ?

This 'getPosts' API will be hit a lot, so I think it would be great to avoid 2 calls - if possible - for this particular function call

Comment: In concept, you can use the Aggregate Framework to do more complex queries in one shot.  I was not, however, able to find a way to use something like $nin as part of an aggregate query. It generally is better in your case to embed the information in the User or Post schema rather than (or in addition to) another collection, in my experience.